# Prusa i3 MK3S supports fail to print on bed

Tags: support-structures, print-failure

My printer currently has issues printing supports of multiple objects. The support gets smushed around the printbed after a while. I’ve attached a picture of the failed support.

I’ve tried lowering and raising the first layer height but it doesn’t seem to have effect. Also I’ve tried raising the heated bed to 70 degree.

How could it happen that it’s pushing the supports around?

I’m using a 0.25 mm nozzle, bed heated at 70 or 60 °C, nozzle at 210 or 215 °C, layer height lowered 0.050 and raised 0.050. I use 7x7 mesh bed leveling. Reran calibration wizard.

[image: Printer fail support]

Comment: Serious underextrusion here but only in the parts on the sides.

Comment: It’s printing the supports like that. I’ve now readjusted the first layer up 0.1mm, wich i think was way too much but it seems to have better results than 0.05 up from where I was printing fine before.

Comment: What's your first layer? a 0.25 mm nozzle only allows to print up to 0.2 mm thick layers! Also, wipe down your print bed with some alcohol to ged rid of fingerprints.

Comment: It is difficult to see, but over-extrusion and a nozzle too far from the bed is my best guess based on this image quality.

Comment: @Marco: There are all sorts of ways you can perturb and possibly "improve" the first layer by adusting the distance to the bed and otherp parameters, but the only one that's not going to break other things is getting the distance *right* (accurate).

Comment: @0scar it's a very very small piece, this image is more detailed than my eyes can see. Why do you think over and the other thinks under?

Comment: @marco: whether it's over or under depends on how much you've messed up the distance to the bed.